# Creating symlink without getting the error "Too many symbolic links"

Tags: symlink

It happens very often if I want to create a symlink:
I'm getting the error `Too many symbolic links`. What does this mean and why can I only solve this error when I'm in the dir where I want to create the symlink?

For example:

```
cd /foo/bar
/foo/bar: sudo ln -s /some/dir /foo/bar
```

This works.

This gives me the error:

```
cd ~
~: sudo ln -s /some/dir /foo/bar
```

Comment: And what do  `ls -l /foo`, `ls -l /some`  and `ls -l /some/dir` show? there must be a link that is looping somewhere.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't specific enough. These are example paths and it is more a general question. My core question is: why do I have to be in the dir where the symlink should be?

Comment: @CrazyDuck, you don't. Not in general. But if you show just a made-up situation, it's impossible to concretely investigate it. That error message hints at a loop of symlinks, so look into that. Or, if you have a real situation, show it exactly: the exact commands you use, and the exact errors you get.

Comment: I recommend that you use the `-t` or `-T` (as appropriate) option of gnu `ln`. It will avoid many error cases. I also suspect that the error was cased by an earlier use or `ln`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example shows you changing to the directory `/foo/bar` before trying to create the symbolic link.  So `/foo/bar` exists already, as either a directory or a symbolic link to another directory.

Then your command:  `ln -s /some/dir /foo/bar` tries to create `/foo/bar` as a link to `/some/dir`.  This must fail, as `/foo/bar` already exists.

It appears you have the file/dir arguments swapped in your command.  To create a link with `ln -s`, the first file/dir must exist and the second one must not exist.  (This is a lot like a cp command)

For your core question, you don't have to be in any particular location to successfully create a symbolic link.  The `ln -s` command can take full paths to either the source or destination (or both), or it can take relative paths.  As long as you have the permissions to create the link in the parent directory of the destination, you can create it without your working directory being in either path.

Answer (score 1):

It could be caused by an earlier use of `ln`. You may have messed up the target.

E.g. this will cause the error.

```
ln -s -T aaa aaa
ln -s -t aaa bbb
```

or in the more ambigues old form

```
ln -s aaa aaa
ln -s bbb aaa/
```